# How to pass props to route components when using useRoutes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying out the new `useRoutes` hook from `react-router-dom` and it seems to be pretty interesting. The only problem, is that I can't figure out how I would pass props down to the components.

Before, I'd have a `Route` component, and I would select parts of local or global state there and pass it on, but how would I do it with `useRoutes`?

In the below sandbox, I'm trying to change the background based on the boolean value of `isLoading`. How would I pass `isLoading` on?

[image: mystifying-paper-1khwd]

## Edit

Here's the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Outlet, useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";

const Main = ({ isLoading }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      height: "40vh",
      width: "50vw",
      backgroundColor: isLoading ? "red" : "pink"
    }}
  >
    <Outlet />
  </div>
);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Main />
  }
];

const App = ({ isLoading }) => {
  const routing = useRoutes(routes);
  return (
    <>
      {routing}
      {JSON.stringify(isLoading)}
    </>
  );
};

export default function Entry() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setIsLoading(!isLoading);
    }, 3000);
  }, [isLoading]);
  return (
    <Router>
      <App isLoading={isLoading} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

## Edit

I've considered passing in an `isLoading` argument to `routes`, but I feel like that won't be an efficient approach, because the whole tree will rerender at any route, regardless of whether or not it depends on `isLoading` or doesn't. Would a better approach be to use `Switch` and a custom `Route` component for routes that depend on `isLoading` and just use `useSelector` in that custom `Route` component?

Comment: Please put your code here, on this site, in your question, as an edit.  Do not just link to external code repos.  It needs to be here as well.  You can keep the link as long as the code is here as well.  If code sandbox ever dies, your question no longer helps future visitors because they cannot see the original code.

Comment: Sure, I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```js
    const routes = (props) => [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Main {...props} />
      }
    ];
    
    const App = ({ isLoading }) => {
      const routing = useRoutes(routes({isLoading}));
      return (
        <>
          {routing}
          {JSON.stringify(isLoading)}
        </>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Why would this work though? Code dumps aren’t helpful to learning. Explain the changes so op can learn

Comment: A code dump is fine, I'm aware of what he's saying. I'm just wondering if it's the [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64880605/how-to-pass-props-to-route-components-when-using-useroutes/64880772#comment114709914_64880722) way

Comment: @MikeK i haven't looked into it, but maybe you can create a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) with your `isLoading` state, wrap your routing in the context provider, and make your components grab the value from the context. But, wouldn't it be too much? It depends on your actual use case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the array, you can create a function that returns a constructed array to the useRoutes hook:

```
const routes = (isLoading) => [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Main isLoading={isLoading} />
  }
];
```

code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-dream-hx1y9

Comment: I've thought of this, but would this be the only way? The whole tree will rerender, and it could get inefficient if there are many children. It's simple with Redux's `useSelector` to have an nth child be aware of a certain state change, but if Redux was not at my disposal, would this be my only approach?

Answer (score 0):

more pretty would be:

```
const routes = (props) => [
  {
    "/": () => <Main {...props} />
  }
];
    
    
    const App = ({ isLoading }) => {
      const routing = useRoutes(routes(isLoading));

      return (
           <>
               {routing}
               {JSON.stringify(isLoading)}
           </>
      )
    };
```